# Is it possible to select from a list with a list without iteration?

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I want to stop using foreach for my List every time I need a list of objects.

```
 IEnumerable<int> myKeys = _context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Name == name);

 foreach(var key in keys)
{     
    var myObject = _context.FirstOrDefault(x => x.key == key);
   _context.MySecondTable.Remove(myObject);
}
```

Does a method exist in linq that would allow me to pass in the list of keys or am I stuck iterating through my keys and getting my objects one key at a time?

I am hoping to use RemoveRange();

```
_context.MySecondTable.RemoveRange(myObjects);
```

Comment: I might be the only one, but I don't understand what you're expecting the `SomeLinqMethodThatTakesACollectionToSearchBy` method to do. Can you post the code that you'd normally use for your task?

Comment: @Vache I updated the way I am currently using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<int> myKeys = _context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Name == name);

foreach(var obj in _context.MySecondTable.Where(o => myKeys.Contains(o.key))
    var myObject = _context.Remove(obj);
```

Or if your context supports multiple deletes:

```
var myKeys = _context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Name == name);
var myObject = _context.RemoveRange(
    _context.MySecondTable.Where(o => myKeys.Contains(o.key));
```

Comment: This still iterates the object. I was hoping to pass myKeys to a method and then call RemoveRange()

Comment: @Robert I was just editing with that :) check it. However, regarding the iterating version, note that you get rid of the `FirstOrDefault` per-item database query.